# How to define a go-gin route with an id in the middle

Tags: go, go-gin

I want to define a route

```
/user/{userid}/status
```

How can I define this kind of route and intercept the userid in handler. Something like this

```
 r.GET("/user/{userid}/status", userStatus)
```

How can read the userid variable in my Go code in such case?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You may use `userid := c.Param("userid")`, like this working sample:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "net/http"

    "github.com/gin-gonic/gin"
)

func main() {
    router := gin.Default()

    router.GET("/user/:userid/status", func(c *gin.Context) {
        userid := c.Param("userid") 
        message := "userid is " + userid
        c.String(http.StatusOK, message)
        fmt.Println(message)
    })

    router.Run(":8080")
}
```